# Why is robot framework returning 'While' is a reserved keyword

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to setup a simple while loop, but I keep getting this error:

> 'While' is a reserved keyword.

Robot Framework 4.1.3 (Python 3.8.10 on linux)

For sanity, I stripped everything out and created the following test with examples straight from the robotcorp docs (https://robocorp.com/docs/languages-and-frameworks/robot-framework/while-loops)

While.robot

```
*** Settings ***

*** Variables ***
@{ROBOTS}=        Bender    Johnny5    Terminator    Robocop

*** Keywords ***

*** Test Cases ***

Loop Over A List Of Items And Log Each Of Them
    FOR    ${robot}    IN    @{ROBOTS}
        Log    ${robot}
    END

Testing While Loop
    ${x}=    Set Variable    ${0}
    WHILE    ${x} < 3
        ${x}=    Evaluate    ${x} + 1
        IF    ${x} == 2
            CONTINUE    #  Skip this iteration.
        END
        Log    x = ${x}    # x = 1, x = 3
    END
```

The result:

```
$ robot tests/While.robot 
==============================================================================
While                                                                         
==============================================================================
Loop Over A List Of Items And Log Each Of Them                        | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing While Loop                                                    | FAIL |
'While' is a reserved keyword.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
While                                                                 | FAIL |
2 tests, 1 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Am I missing something or is this broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `WHILE` is a reserved keyword, but not working on that version of Robot Framework, 4.1.3.

You probably are seeing the documentation of the future version, 5.0.

The first Beta version was just released **today**. See [this post](https://forum.robotframework.org/t/robot-framework-5-0-beta-1-has-been-released/3249) on the Forum:

> pekkaklarck
> Pekka Klärck
>
> Robot Framework 5.0 is a big new major release with lot of interesting
> new features such as TRY/EXCEPT, WHILE, inline IF, RETURN, BREAK and
> CONTINUE syntax, support for custom argument conversion in libraries
> and various enhancements to xUnit outputs. Robot Framework 5.0 only
> works with Python 3.6 or newer. Robot Framework 5.0 beta 1 is the
> second preview release and contains the majority of the planned new
> features. For more details see the full release notes 4. (...)

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see any version references in the documentation content or URL.  Is this a documentation issue I should report?

Comment: I think you don't need to report, on robotcorp, because this should be a temporary thing, and the official documentation for the release 4.1.3 is what should be taken into account.

Comment: Where is the official documentation for 4.1.3?

Comment: The official released version is always here: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/
And the Release Notes, for each version, here: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/releases